# Mesh from .svg won't form correctly

Tags: mesh, svg

[image: Mesh after extruding faces]
[image: Mesh]
So when I make a mesh it will not make enough vertices around the edge and I'm left with a fragmented face. It has done this on every single .svg file I have tried.

Comment: What's your question? How it should look like at the end? I recommend specify your goal and add the geometry to your question in order to test...

Comment: Try to fill faces manually.

Comment: maybe share your svg so that we can give a try? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wcQOOpT9yXovBgpU9MQ49tOhybt-62Bo/view?usp=sharing this is my svg

Comment: @brockmann I am asking why the faces of the numbers aren't smooth and how I fix them. I am following this tutorial https://youtu.be/nCowrvfOr3Q but I can't seem to get past the first few steps in Blender.

Comment: @FFeller how do I do that? Sorry I really don't know how to use Blender.

Comment: weird because the conversion to mesh works fine here, I can't tell why it's not the case for you

Comment: @moonboots dang... maybe you could send me the blender file with it already converted? you don't have to though.

Comment: what operation do you do exactly? Import as SVG, scale up, convert to mesh?

Comment: @moonboots all I did was import as SVG, convert to mesh, then extrude faces. I'm trying to follow the tutorial I linked above if you are wondering what I am trying to do.

Comment: see the picture here: https://zupimages.net/up/21/15/10xl.jpg ... it looks like it converts and extrudes correctly, so I'm not able to tell you why it doesn't work for you

Comment: @moonboots hm okay. well, thank you for trying! I don't mean to be demanding or rude, but if you could export the blender file and link it to me, that would be so so so so so amazing. I've been able to do everything else in this project except this one part, but this one part has held me up for months. You don't have to though, you've already done a ton for me.

Comment: sure, here it is, btw you could clean them up a bit with a X > Limited Dissolve: https://pasteall.org/blend/97c2fdedd3df46aba2ae1c473dc96b3d